# Masonry item margin-bottom issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've activated Masonry on the parent element (an unordered list) that houses the modified list items listed below (with Chrome's F12 DEV tools showing the margin-bottom and margin-right in the pink-ish color):

[image: Masonry Problem before Resizing]

When the document is loaded, the above occurs despite the CSS of each list item being the following;

```
li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The jQuery I used is the following;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").masonry({
        itemSelector: 'li'
    });
});
```

Once the window is resized horizonally, however, the CSS styles come into effect as shown below;

[image: Masonry Problem Solved by Resizing]

Any idea as to how I can acheive the above on page load?

**UPDATE***

JSFiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/r9kq05hz/1/). If the said problem doesn't appear, try clicking the 'Run' button (Ctrl + Return).

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: How do you size your Elements? fixed or with %? - dumb Question ;)

Comment: @j_s_stack the ul is sized at 100% of parent (body), and the li are (50% - 10px)

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#gutter for the Horrizontal Space

Comment: @RavinduL So the issue is that when the page loads there is no space between them when there should be?

Answer (score 6):

For the webkit browser problem I simply added `$(window).load(function(){` before `('#masonry').masonry({`. Now the margin-bottom is fine on every item on every browser.

Comment: I had to do this too, I assume because images were involved.

Comment: This is the right way to do it ! Works without gutter to fix the bootstrap flex width issue

Answer (score 2):

It works finde as sone as I add `gutter: 10` ;

```
$("ul#news").masonry({
    itemSelector: 'li',
    gutter: 10
});
```

Explenation: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#gutter

Comment: If you have a look on Item #3 in the DEV Tools What does it say/show

Comment: it seems like ist depends on the Browser you user

Comment: Hmm yes... It works perfectly in Internet Explorer... Apparently it  becomes defective only on Webkit browsers like Chrome... Do you know a workaround that might fix this?

Comment: no Idea - but Firefox also doesnt get it quit right

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until now.

I've removed all margins altogether and let masonry handle it ("gutter"-option) and it works fine!

Hope that helps!